# Clearing Administrative Events Log in Windows10

Tags: windows-10

There are over 19,000 events in my Administrator Event Listing ... and, they appear to be most minor ... but, there ARE some identified as "Critical" ... and, everything I find that explains how to clear the logs across the board is beyond my technical expertise ... Besides the fact that "saving" the events is part of almost every method ... which I do not understand the need to do so ... IS THERE NO SIMPLE WAY TO SIMPLY CLEAR/DELETE THE MANY EVENTS ???

Comment: Please provide specifics, on what part of the process you are confused about, be sure you provide details on what process you are following percisely.  Normally all it would take to clear this list, is going into the event manager, and clearing them.

Answer (score 4):

#### How To Clear Administrative Events Log

The Administrative Events log (listed under Custom Views) in the Event Viewer is a Filter that contains all of the event from the System, Security and Application event logs.

You can either clear these individual logs, or use the instructions below to clear all the event logs.

---

#### To Clear All Event Logs in Event Viewer in Windows

**`cmd` shell solution**:

> 1. Open an elevated command prompt.
> 2. Run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    for /f "tokens=*" %1 in ('wevtutil.exe el') do wevtutil.exe cl "%1"
>    ```
> 3. The event logs will now be cleared and the `cmd` shell can be closed.

**`PowerShell` solution:**

> 1. Open an elevated Windows PowerShell.
> 2. Run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    wevtutil el | Foreach-Object {wevtutil cl "$_"}
>    ```
> 3. The event logs will now be cleared, and PowerShell can be closed.

Source [How to Clear All Event Logs in Event Viewer in Windows](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16588-event-viewer-clear-all-event-logs-windows.html)

---

#### To Clear Individual Event Viewer Logs in Event Viewer

> 1. Press the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys to open the
>      *Run* dialog, type *eventvwr.msc*, and click *OK*.
> 2. Select a log (example: Application) that you want to clear in the left pane of Event Viewer, and click on *Clear Log* in the far right
>      *Actions* pane.
>
>    <kbd>[image]</kbd>
>
> OR
>
> 3. Right click on a log (example: Application) that you want to clear in the left pane of Event Viewer, and click *Clear
>      Log*.
>
>    <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Source [How to Clear All Event Logs in Event Viewer in Windows](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16588-event-viewer-clear-all-event-logs-windows.html)